# Editing field_value using mysql - error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

My question relates to ContactFormDB WordPress plugin.

I am looking for a way to edit the field_value but am getting syntax errors with the SQL code below. I would appreciate any help.

UPDATE wp_cf7dbplugin_submits 
SET `field_value`='Order Complete'
WHERE
`submit_time`=1368356907.7434, 
`form_name`='Submission Page', 
`field_name`='status'

Answer (score 0):

use `AND` or `OR` to separate multiple condition, not comma.

```
UPDATE  wp_cf7dbplugin_submits 
SET     field_value = 'Order Complete'
WHERE   submit_time = 1368356907.7434 AND
        form_name = 'Submission Page' AND
        field_name = 'status'
```

just change `AND` if it does not fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks man,that worked.

P.S. I am a massive newbie if that wasn't apparent.